# Magento 1.9 Method not found in Mage_Core_Model_Abstract

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a custom method in my *Shipping Model class*

```
public function getCustomMethod()
{
    return 'test';
}
```

But whenever I want to call the custom method using **Mage::*getModel*** in my *Helper class*

```
Mage::getModel('custom_shipping/myclass')->getCustomMethod();
```

I'm getting the error:

> Method not found in Mage_Core_Model_Abstract

I understand that the *Shipping Model* extends **`Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract`** and not the **`Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`**

I know I have an option to create another Model class that extends **`Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`** to remove the error but I want to call it as it is.

So, how can I call my custom method *getCustomMethod()* which is inside the *Shipping Model class*?

Link to related questions and or articles is highly appreciated.

UPDATE: Added **`config.xml`** tag for model

```
<global>
    <models>
        <trunkrs_customcourier>
            <class>Trunkrs_CustomCourier_Model</class>
        </trunkrs_customcourier>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: can you show me your config.xml file models tag?

Comment: @pankajparmar bai, added olready